# access test data after test area in cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress, web-testing

I have an html code with contains

```js
<div class="form-card">

  <h2 class="fs-title" test-data="area_1">
    About DigCompEdu
  </h2>

  <p></p>

  <label for="academic_teaching" class="question" test-data="question_1">
    <b>1- </b>
  </label>
  <small id="academic_teachingHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
  </small>

  <div class="form-check question-form-check ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" value="0" id="3" name="2" test-data="answer_1" />
      </div>

    </div>
```

So, I have h1 with testdata name after that i have a form, this form contains question with multin check radio .. i want to access this check , not by just call ([test-data="answer_2"])
because i have another tips and don't want to check them as this one ,

i did smth like this but it's not working :

```
cy.get('[test-data="area_1"]~[test-data="answer_2"]').check({force: true})
```

Any one have another idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the `~` between the selectors, I haven't seen that before.

Does it work with a space between instead?

```js
cy.get('[test-data="area_1"] [test-data="answer_2"]').check({force: true})
```

---

If the heading is followed by the form like this

```html
<h2 class="fs-title"  test-data="area_1">
  About DigCompEdu
</h2> 
<div class="form-check question-form-check ">
  ...
```

then you would query like this

```js
cy.get('[test-data="area_1"]')
  .next('.form-check')                // next element on page
  .find('[test-data="answer_2"]')     // this looks inside '.form-check'
  .check({force: true})
```

Comment: no, it's not .. it's give  `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: [test-data="area_1"] [test-data="answer_2"], but never found it.`

Comment: Ok, so how are the two HTML connected? That's key to setting up the right selector.

Comment: they started with `<div class="form-card">` then `<h2 class="fs-title"  test-data="area_1">` and  `<div class="form-check question-form-check ">` and inside this div have `<input class="radio" type="radio"  value="0" id="3" name="2"  test-data="answer_1" />`

Comment: I updated the question, i give you the wrong path.. can you check it please ?

Comment: You can use `.sibling('.form-check')` instead of `.next('.form-check')`. Sibling command scans everything at the same level, and when you add a selector inside it filters according to that selector.

Comment: yes it's working, but why check doesn't appear ?

Comment: no check in the radio happend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031952/access-data-from-html-to-test-it-in-cypress can you check it please ?